# Совмещение двух псевдоклассов

Tags: html, css

Как совместить для одного параметра в CSS `:last-child` и `:hover`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`:last-child:hover`

Comment: В IE6 будет восприниматься только последний псевдо-класс :hover (не уверен, т.к. не проверял; может автору вопроса пригодится)

Comment: IE6 такой IE6...  
Он и :hover понимает только для ссылок.

Answer (score 0):

Не слышали про группировку селекторов?

```
селектор, селектор {
  свойство: значение;
  свойство: значение;
  свойство: значение;
}
```

В вашем случае:

```
что-то:last-child, что-то:hover {
 . . . .
}
```